# Diagnose of lagging Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, gnome, dell

A few days ago, my Ubuntu 16.04 starts lagging. So I decided to reinstall it, but even after re-installation the lagging continues. Writing in PhpStorm is slow, the suggestion is terrible, Spotify is visually slow while I browse music, Firefox is totally slow, it can not even load my emails - it takes approximately 40 seconds to load my inbox. I have tried Ubuntu Gnome, different Linux kernels, switch graphical drivers, set vm.swappiness to 1. Nothing helped.

How could I diagnose what is happening with my computer? In the past everything worked smoothly and without problems.

I own Dell XPS 15, 8GB RAM, i7-6700HQ, 256GB SSD

EDIT: I think, that the slow behavior started since I unplug adapter from my notebook for a while. Is there a possibility, that my notebook gets into some save mode and can not get out of it? Output from `sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` shows `799 906` it is pretty slow, right?

Answer (score 1):

Lagging effect with different kernels suggests to me that it's not a kernel issue per se, so it probably is something in userspace that could be throttling or rate limiting your machine.  One thing to check for is thermal overrun on the CPU and if the CPU is being speed throttled by thermald. The output from dmesg may be useful as that will show if there are any thermal overruns or throttling occurring.

Comment: Output from dmesg is really messy, I do not get it what should I looking for. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had to unplug my battery a wait approximately 1 minute. Then, output from `sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` shows `3 426 210`

Comment: Problems with Dell computers and battery and chargers and their interaction with the intel_pstate cpu frequency scaling driver are well known. The issue is with Dell's use of Clock Modulation, which is incompatible with one of the algorithms used in the driver.

Comment: @DougSmythies How could I would future problems with it? Some tips?

Comment: In the most recent mainline kernels, and for most computers, the intel_pstate driver uses a different algorithm, and should be O.K. with clock modulation. I do not know when this will trickle down to distribution kernels. You can disable the intel_pstate driver, which will result in using the acpi-cpufreq frequency scaling driver instead.